# Error sending letters during registration

Tags: typescript, sendmail, nestjs

I want to send a letter to the user during registration. I found a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nest-modules/mailer) for this.
Following the instructions I added to my app.model.

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        UsersModule,
        AuthModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
        MailerModule.forRoot({
            transport: 'smtps://myName@myCompanyName.com:myPassword@smtp.myCompanyName.com',
            defaults: { from: '"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>' },
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Next, I added an email sending function to the authorization service.

```
export class AuthController {
    constructor(
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        private readonly usersService: UsersService,
        private readonly mailerService: MailerService,
    ) {}

    @Post('register')
    public async register(@Response() res, @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<ResultRegister> {
        const isUser = await this.usersService.findByEmail(createUserDto.email);
        if (isUser) {
            throw new HttpException({ message: 'User exists' }, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }
        this.mailerService
            .sendMail({
                to: 'myName@myCompanyName.com', // sender address
                from: createUserDto.email, // list of receivers
                subject: 'Testing Nest MailerModule ✔', // Subject line
                text: 'welcome', // plaintext body
                html: '<b>welcome</b>', // HTML body content
            })
            .then(succ => console.log('succ:', succ))
            .catch(err => console.log('err:', err));
        const { success, message } = await this.authService.register(createUserDto);
        if (!success) {
            throw new HttpException(message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({ success, message });
    }
}
```

When I register, I get a response that the user has registered and I get an error in the console.

```
err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 188.234.113.78:465
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '188.234.113.78',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

I do not quite understand what this error means and where I made a mistake. What is my mistake when I send an email to a user?

Comment: Is this on your localhost or on an application hosting service (like Heroku, Google Cloud, or AWS)?

Comment: @Jay McDoniel It is local, I do it on my working computer

Comment: Are you sure you set up settings for mailer module correctly?

Comment: @Jay McDoniel Yes, I indicated the correct data of my work account from Google

Comment: That IP address is not one that is known to me, is that what you are using as your local machine somehow (instead of 127.0.0.1). I don't see anything in nodemailer (or the nest variant) about that IP address

Comment: @Jay McDoniel Maybe the problem is in my working account from google?

Comment: @MegaRoks are you saying you are trying to execute this code remotely? I'm not sure I'm following

Comment: @Jay McDoniel No, I'm trying to execute this code on my working computer.

Comment: Do you know where that IP address comes from? It is abnormal from the normal localhost...

Comment: @Jay McDoniel No, I don’t know where this IP address is from.